# SwiftUI - Syncing ScrollViews

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

How would I make two ScrollViews sync whilst scrolling?

ScrollView (A) - On the left of the screen, moves vertically up and down

ScrollView (B) - On the right, moves vertically and horizontally.

If A moves up and down, B should move the same vertical distance and vice versa

```
-----------------------------------------------
|            |                                |
|            |                                |
|     A      |                B               |
|            |                                |
|  Scrolls   |    Scrolls both Horizontally   |
| Vertically |           & Vertically         |
|            |                                |
----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Probably not a good fit for SwiftUI -- better to drop into UIKit/AppKit for something like that.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm need exactly the same thing using swiftui on macOS